# Restore shutdown to root only

Tags: shutdown

I've changed the shutdown command to be able to run it as normal user (not root):

```
sudo chmod a+s /sbin/shutdown
```

And now I cannot get back to root only when running shutdown:

```
$ sudo chmod a-s /sbin/shutdown 
$ ls -l /sbin/shutdown 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 May  5 20:55 /sbin/shutdown -> /bin/systemctl

$ ls -l /bin/systemctl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 659848 May  5 20:55 /bin/systemctl
```

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x` looks fine to me: no SUID bit there any more. Can you still run it as a regular user?

Comment: yes, shutdown can be issued with normal user with no restrictions

Comment: Then it certainly isn't because of the permissions on the executable. Did you change any other access policy or permissions that may affect this?

Comment: no, just added s bit and removing it to shutdown